# Eclipse "top level elements" changes to "Working sets" on change of perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I close my perspective B, and open it again, even if the B perspective "top level elements" property was "Projects", it gets changed to "top level elements".

However please note that when I open up the perspective the very first time, the property was "Projects".

I am sorry if this question is very elementary but I am quite new to Eclipse development.

Does anyone know which class this property belongs to, so I can override it when the Perspective is opened?

I suspect it should belong Common Navigator Framework and specifically the CommonNavigator class?

P.S. What would be the correct way to know such things, i.e. where is such an action defined and what function is it bind to? Is there any direct way or does it need a person with full knowledge of the eclipse framework?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same view? Package Explorer and Project Explorer look quite similar.

Comment: It is a custom Project view. And it happens when I close the perspective and open it again. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well just closing and opening a normal Project Explorer view always seems to revert to Working Sets so it looks like the view does not persist this setting.

You can find out some things about what classes are used by using [Eclipse plug-in spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy). You can also look at the plugin definitions and the source code. Project Explorer is in the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` plugin.

It looks like `org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.workingsets.WorkingSetsContentProvider` deals with this setting but I don't see an obvious way to change it.

Comment: WorkingSetsConentProvider uses IExtensionStateModel.getBooleanProperty("org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.workingSets.showTopLevelWorkingSets") to set the CommonNavigator.rootMode(int) 

So perhaps setting this property, if I am able to get a handle IExtensionStateModel will do the trick